# No .xml files extracted in content migration package (.cmp)

Tags: 2010, variations

Currently we have a SharePoint 2010 Enterprise installation running on a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise box with SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise as our back end database.

We're currently working on a project to translate our site into various languages and are utilizing the `Export Variations` feature in the `Manage Content and Structure` view. When using the export feature, the site loading bar spins for some time and then the content migration package (`.cmp`) file downloads. I'm following along [this blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/11/14/sharepoint-variations-the-complete-guide-part-1-the-basics.aspx) to learn how to implement SharePoint variations. After the `.cmp` file is downloaded to my local machine, the article(s) said that the extension should be changed to `.cab` so that we can see the files contained inside. For all other subsites, several `.xml` files were contained in the packaged file (including `TranslatableFieldSettings.xml` and `Manifest.xml`). For this particular file though, I only have `.dat` files.

Unfortunately, I've exhausted all my SharePoint knowledge and resources. I've ensured all files in the directory are checked in and re-run the export to no success. This directory contains a lot of static CMS content. In fact it is our largest one in terms of storing copy that is displayed on the pages. Does anyone have any ideas? Could this possibly be a data size issue preventing the export from completing successfully and causing it to error out silently?

Comment: try this one and let us know...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jojok/archive/2011/09/10/exporting-variations.aspx

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Will do. I'll post the results soon. Thanks for the fast reply.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get the above mentioned solution to work. I've tried increasing some file size limits in some config files as well but still not luck. The same result occurs, file downloads but no .xml contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I managed to resolve the problem. I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.deployment.spexportsettings.filemaxsize(v=office.14).aspx) on the Microsoft MSDN site. One section in particular caught my eye:

> By default, the .cmp files are limited to 24 MB in size, although you can change this value using the FileMaxSize property. If set to zero, the value resets to the default.

This stood out to me right away as the two subsites that I was having problems with were the two largest subsites on the site.

The next paragraph states the following:

> When site data exceeds the specified limit, site data is separated in to two or more migration files. However, if a single site data file exceeds the maximum file size, the operation does not split the source file, but rather it resizes the .cmp file to accommodate the oversize file. You can have any number of .cmp files.

For us, this was not the case. We were having content migration packages (.cmp) files returned with a file size of 0 KB. To this day, I will cannot get the GUI "Export Variation" option to work.

We did find a work around however. The work around utilizes the `Export-SPWeb` functionality built into the SharePoint Administration Console (PowerShell). The functionality is defined as follows:

> `Export-SPWeb http://site -Path "site export.cmp"`

The full description can be fond [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895(v=office.15).aspx).

By specifying our subsite (`http://site/subsite`), the local path to extract the file to (`C:\Location\name.cmp`) and setting the `CompressionSize` to `999999`, we were able to extract out a full copy of the content migration package. Packages extracted via this method override the size limitation and do contain the required `.xml` files.

**Importing:**

There is a function called `Import-SPWeb` which manually uploads the package back into SharePoint. We tested this functionality as well and confirmed that it did indeed work. The format for this command is the following:

> `Import-SPWeb http://site -Path export.cmp -UpdateVersions Overwrite`

The full description can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613(v=office.15).aspx).